# How to evaluate an array of numbers over a list of functions without loop control structures?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

Given an array of points:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

and a list of functions:

```
f = [lambda x:x>2,lambda x: x==2]
```

the lengths of `x` and `f` are arbitrary. I want to find out, which `xi` (in `x`) satisfies all functions out of `f`. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

def search(x, f):
    finalList = [] # Final list that contains the results
    r = []
    for i in range(len(f)):
         r.append(f[i](x)) # Evaluate all x's over ith function 
    np.array(r)
    r = np.transpose(r)
    for i in range(len(r)):
        finalList.append(i) if np.all(r[i]) else False
    return finalList
```

I know that my algorithm is naive(but works) maybe there are unnecessary steps and but is there any way to avoid `for` loop here or is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: Why do you write `np.array(r)`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i initialised r as a list , so i turned it later to an array to take the transpose of !

Comment: but then you should write `r = np.array(r)`. Furthermore it is useless since you do it with `transpose(..)` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it like this, if I understood what you need:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
f = [lambda x: x>2,lambda x: x==2]
result = [i for i in x if all([fun(i) for fun in f])]
```

And if you want to return element's position rather than element:

```
result = [e for e, i in enumerate(x) if all([fun(i) for fun in f])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here two solutions without loops, that work for an arbitrary number of functions:

Solution 1 (one liner):

```
result = x[reduce(lambda y, z: y & z, map(lambda cond: cond(x), f))]
```

Solution 2:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
f = [lambda x:x>2,lambda x: x==2]

each_cond = map(lambda cond: filter(cond, x), f)

def list_intersection(it_list):
    sets = iter(map(set, it_list))
    result = sets.next()
    for s in sets:
        result = result.intersection(s)
    return list(result)

result = list_intersection(each_cond)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another straightforward way is to use

```
for fn in f:
    res = np.apply_along_axis(fn, -1, x)
    # do further stuff & return
```

But, why do you want to have a list of functions? Isn't it not possible to do it in a single condition like this?

```
In [15]: x
Out[15]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [16]: (x > 2) & (x == 2)
Out[16]: array([False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

# or combining everything
In [18]: np.all((x > 2) & (x == 2))
Out[18]: False
```

Comment: Sometimes no , cuz it could be anything and i have no clue what will the user insert as a function actually it's completely unknown to me what set of conditions user going to insert !